# Implement Dynamic Property Assignment in Kotlin

Tags: php, kotlin, dynamic

```
data class Person private constructor(
   var name: ObservableField<String> = ObservableField("Tony Starks"),
   var age: ObservableField<Int> = ObservableField(40),
   var gender: ObservableField<String> = ObservableField("Male"),
   var test: String = "Tony Starks",
) {
   operator fun set(key: String, value: String) {
       // Tried this approach but it didn't work.
       this[key] = value
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is this;

```
val person = Person()
person['test'] = "James Bond"
```

I've been able to achieve the same thing with PHP

```
class Person {
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $gender;
  
    public __get($key) {
      return $this[$key];
    }
  
    public __set($key, $value) {
        $this[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Kotlin?

Comment: pretty sure that kotlin is a strongly typed language, and PHP is not

Comment: It wouldn't have worked anyway (without doing the stuff in Tenfour04's answer) but your ``operator`` ``set`` function up there calls ``this[key] = ``, which is just calling itself (``set``) again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kind of behavior is an anti-pattern in a strongly typed language like Kotlin. It is usually wise not to try to force a strongly-typed language to behave like a weakly-typed one. Your entire way of thinking and design should be different when working with a strongly-typed language.

That said, it is possible to get a similar syntax by making your class a MutableMap and [delegating the relevant properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) to itself. You can make it a MutableMap either through delegation, as shown below, or by subclassing HashMap. However, you cannot make this a `data class` if you are using property delegates.

```
class Person: MutableMap<String, Any?> by mutableMapOf() {
    var test: String by this
    init {
        test = "Tony Stark"
    }

    override fun toString() = "Person(test='$test')"
}

fun main()  {
    val person = Person()
    println(person)
    person["test"] = "Pepper Potts"
    println(person)
    person.test = "Happy Hogan"
    println(person["test"])
}

/** Prints:
Person(test='Tony Stark')
Person(test='Pepper Potts')
Happy Hogan
*/
```

Downsides to doing this (which are similar to problems in a weakly typed language) are:

- It will crash if you neglect to set an initial value for the property before retrieving it
- It will crash if you have a typo in the property name
- It will silently fail to change the desired property if you have a typo in the name when setting it.

The reason Kotlin makes it possible to delegate properties to a Map, despite it usually being an antipattern, is that it has uses when working with runtime dynaic data such as JSON that you may be converting back and forth between class representations.